# Music through Sprite Kit Scenes?

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit, scene, background-music

So I have a sprite kit game and I'm adding music to it. The music worked fine and worked until I decided to add a slider to control the music volume. So to do this I added another scene for the "options menu." The problem is, when I exit the scene to go to the actual game interface, the game music completely disappears. Also I'm having trouble removing the actual slider. My code for the options scene will be listed down below. (It is still in the making) I'm new to this website so I'm sorry if the code is messed up.

```
@interface OptionsScene ()
@property BOOL contentCreated;
@end
```

@implementation OptionsScene

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size
{
if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
    self.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);

}
return self;
}

-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view
{
    NSString *music = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"InAmberClad" ofType:@"mp3"];
    backGroundMusic = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:music] error:NULL];
    backGroundMusic.delegate = self;
    backGroundMusic.numberOfLoops = -1;
    [backGroundMusic play];



CGRect frame = CGRectMake(200, 300, 150, 10);
_volumeSlider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[_volumeSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(volumeControl) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
_volumeSlider.maximumValue = 1;
_volumeSlider.minimumValue = 0;
_volumeSlider.continuous = YES;
[_volumeSlider setValue:0.5];
[_volumeSlider setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

if (!self.contentCreated) {
    [self.view addSubview:_volumeSlider];
    [self createContents];
    self.contentCreated = YES;
}
}

-(void)createContents
{
    self.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
}

-(void)volumeControl
{
[backGroundMusic setVolume:_volumeSlider.value];
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
SKScene *options = [[MyScene alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
[self.view presentScene:options];


}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you don't delegate the backgroundMusic to self, this problem will be solved. Also, before play the music, run a `[backGroundMusic prepareToPlay];` will improve performance.

Here is a link to a tutorial, on page search for "Music" to see how he did it.

[Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/42699/spritekit-tutorial-for-beginners)

Comment: I tried removing the delegate to backGroundMusic self, like completely. Though the music remained cancelled as soon as the scene would exit. The music was working when it was being played in the ViewController class using the same code. Though I've searched it up and I don't think that the view controller can actually add a UISlider, as it doesn't have the 
did move to view void. Should I delegate the backGroundMusic to something else? Also, how can I remove the Slider Subview? I keep on getting errors when I try to.